# How long of a name do you budget for in a template?

Tags: page-layout, text, typesetting

I'm designing a name overlay for a series of videos and I'm curious how long of a name I should budget for without knowing what ones might come my way.

As it's for a video it should be reasonably large, so I can't just make it tiny.  If there's something ridiculously long, I could go and scale it, but the lesser the better.  If only there was a 90th percentile for name length...

Comment: My name full is 15 characters long (with space) :D

Comment: Whatever you do, don't forget to test it against something with more "M"s and "W"s and fewer "i"s and "l"s

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is going to be somewhat dependent:

- on the parts of the world you are targeting
- what parts of a name you need to include (middle names/initials?)
- any other abbreviations that might be needed (Mrs, Dr, PhD, MSc?)
- characters used in names, unless of course you're using a monospaced font

I don't think there's any substitute for sample test data from your intended markets, from which you should indeed be able to derive a 90th percentile, although failing to fit 1 in 10 seems problematic; I'd be tempted to go for 95th percentile or higher.

I happen to have a long list of first and last names here. Difficult to sort them all by actual length in mm, but if I sort them by number of characters, including spaces, the 95th percentile is 19 characters long, including a space.

I can then set all of my 19-character names in my chosen font size, visually check which is the longest and measure it in pixels or mm.

But that's just an example with mostly British data, and I didn't include middle names or initials, or titles; you should definitely do abit of research.