# What is the widest character in the "Helvetica Neue" font?

Tags: website-design, typography

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what is the largest glyph width in Arial?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2978/what-is-the-largest-glyph-width-in-arial)

Doing some web design and I need to give a div a specific size. However, I do know how many characters are in the text box, so what's the widest character that could possibly go in there. If there's none, are all the characters in Helvetica Neue equal width?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's definitely not a monospaced font. Rule of thumb is to check the 'm' and 'M'. Compare that to the 'w' and 'W' and you should have your answer.

Comment: Capital 'W' is the widest.

Comment: I'd also take a look at em dash. Just in case ;).